# Jquery addClass to multiple li

Tags: jquery, menuitem, highlight

I have main navigation structure as below:

```
<li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="about">
        <?php echo nav_about ?>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo BASEURL ?>/about-us.html">
                <?php echo nav_about_profile ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo BASEURL ?>/committee.html">
                <?php echo nav_about_committee ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and a highlight script to respective item while the url and link are matches up:

```
/* highlight nav menu */
$(function(){
    $('#topMain.nav-pills li a').each(function(index) {
        if($.trim(this.href) == stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(window.location.href)) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
    return url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0];
}
```

I can add `active` to its closest hyperlink li, but I want to look for a way to add `active` to very top li as well, which result like:

```
<li class="active"> <-- I NEED THIS CLASS TO BE ADD ALSO
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="about">
        <?php echo nav_about ?>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="<?php echo BASEURL ?>/about-us.html">
                <?php echo nav_about_profile ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo BASEURL ?>/committee.html">
                <?php echo nav_about_committee ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: add class to the top parent li like `parentli` then use `closest()` like `.closest('li.parentli')` if you have like this it will select the top most li like what you wanted

Comment: @guradio, thank you that's work!

Comment: glad to help mate :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li:has(a[href="'+opened_path+'"])').addClass('active')
.parent().closest('li')
.addClass('active');
```